# Interop Excel - How to convert shape into picture at same postion

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to convert Shape of Worksheet into Picture.
The following code convert fine but position is shape.TopLeftCell.
I want to paste Picture at same position of shape (shape.Top and shape.Left)

```
foreach (Shape shape in sheet.Shapes)
{
    shape.CopyPicture();
    sheet.Cells[shape.TopLeftCell.Row, shape.TopLeftCell.Column].PasteSpecial();
    shape.Delete();
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you tried to use a VBA macro recorder to generate a macro where you could find the required methods and properties to get the job done in Excel while doing steps manually?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev thank you for your suggestion. I do as your suggest and find answer as my new comment.

Answer (score 0):

After paste shape as picture, must move picture to position of shape.
Here my code:

```
shape.CopyPicture();
sheet.Cells[shape.TopLeftCell.Row, shape.TopLeftCell.Column].PasteSpecial();
excel.Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft(shape.Left - shape.TopLeftCell.Left);
excel.Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop(shape.Top - shape.TopLeftCell.Top);
shape.Delete();
```